# Uploading video on webserver through POST method in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, restsharp

I would like to upload the video to my webserver.currently I am using RestSharp as a webclient. I am able to upload the images through AddFile() post method. but I donot know how to upload the video file. I am storing the recorded video in isolated storage and now I want to upload the video picking from isolated storage to my webserver.

please let me know your suggestions if anyone similar did for WP7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First load your video from isolated storage into a byte array, then you can upload it:

```
byte[] data;
using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.OpenFile("MyVideo.wmv", FileMode.Open))
    {
        data = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(data, 0, (int)stream.Length);
    }
}

request.AddFile("video", data, "MyVideo.wmv");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did it the same way as i did for images converting them to byte array. but stackoverflow did not allowed me to post my own answer due to required minimum reputation points.